# When B2=B1 AND C2=C1, return result of 1

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a spreadsheet sorted by alphabetical order in Column B. I want a formula that yields a '1' in an extra Column E when B2=B1 AND C2=C1.

Column B is Account Name and Column C is state, I am looking for Name/State matches.

Comment: Isn't it just something like `=IF(B2=B1 AND C2=C1, "1", "")`?

Answer (score 3):

In E2 enter:

**=--AND(B2=B1,C2=C1)**

you can copy this down if required.

Answer (score 1):

You use a combination if `IF` and `AND` in the column E cell, as in

```
=IF(AND(B2=B1, C2=C1), 1, 0)
```

This will leave either a `1` in column E if they both match properly, or a `0` if not.

You can also use simply `=AND(...)`, but this will leave column E with either TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

```
=(B2=B1)*(C2=C1)
```

may suit. The elements return TRUE or FALSE and TRUE * TRUE returns `1`.